# How to use dwmapi to update touch proofing data in Windows10 or later versions？

Tags: windows, registry, touchscreen, dwm

In the tablet settings, I can configure the display corresponding to the touch screen.
Then I find MultiDigiMon.exe changed the registry in

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Pen\Digimon

and MultiDigiMon.exe use dwmapi.Dll to update the setting.

Now I don't want to used MultiDigiMon.exe , I chenaged registry by myself.
But I don't know how to update the setting by API, I only can taskkill dwm.exe,  and the dwm.exe will auto restart and it work well with new setting .

But kill dwm.exe it not a good idea. How to update this setting silently?

This is MSDN.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN

And I used DwmFlush function API , but did not take effect and always return False.

Comment: I can't test it but can you try to call `SendMessageTimeoutW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, NULL, (LPARAM)L"TabletPCDigitizerMappingChanged", 0, 200, NULL);` to force update (from disasm https://i.imgur.com/Ny8Uwe9.png)

Comment: SendMessageTimeoutW only used by windows 7

Comment: "SendMessageTimeoutW only used by windows " what do you mean by that have you tried it?

Comment: In Windows 8 or later ，this way is not useful .

Comment: Please explain what you say

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/tXtTPKD.png  After Win8 is implemented by SetDisplayMapping on line 96 in the picture

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. Have you tried what I said, yes or no?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6hlWmOy.png  Yes